# Most space-efficient format for image with large dimensions but few colors?

Tags: images, compression, jpeg, png, gif

Recently I have had to scale up the dimensions of a gif image by a factor of 2, this resulted in an increase of the file size by about 8 times. While this is not a complete surprise, I can't help but think there should be a format that scales well with such an operation.

Comment: Can the image be remade as a [Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) image or are you stuck as [Raster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics)?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain actually you brought up a good point, except that what I had in mind was something to be used with google maps

Comment: Google maps stores it's data as tiles, then does small shrink (never expand) as you zoom out. Once you have zoomed out enough it sends a new image at the same resolution as the old one but at a different scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression in GIF images is quite primitive and cannot take advantage of redundancy created by upscaling of the image.

I you resize **without anti-aliasing** then well-[optimized](http://imageoptim.com) PNG shouldn't grow by much.

If you resize **with anti-aliasing** then convert the image to JPEG, as this will create lots of new colors and soft edges that are best handled by JPEG.